# Did Yona (Go Ah-sung) have supernatural/special powers in Snowpiercer?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, snowpiercer

In Snowpiercer Yona (17 year old girl) predicted many times what's behind the locked doors before they were opened. She predicted that the first compartment was empty. Then she shouted before opening a train compartment and we saw there were assassins with axes. And lastly we saw that she found the 5 year old boy who was being hidden in the train engine room without any sign.

Did she have any kind of supernatural power? The movie didn't explain clearly about her powers. How did she get them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Being a "train baby", Yona has highly developed hearing ability.

The director said [in an interview](http://fyeahsnowpiercer.tumblr.com/post/92516980636/bong-joon-ho-on-mason-and-namgoong-minsu-in-snowpiercer) that he felt the need to distinguish the people born on the train from those born on earth. Thus, the "train babies" perceive the noise of the train differently (it's natural to them). As these people were born in a dark environment, their sight is hindered, which resulted in developing other senses on a better level (e.g. taste, and aforementioned hearing).

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the wonderful answer with that source. COOL!!

Comment: I would give up some of my eyesight so I can be able predict

Answer (score 1):

I think it's also helpful to remember that her father was the engineer of the security of the doors, and being his daughter, she learned both directly and indirectly from him about the doors, the security and what was beyond - also enormously because how Napoleon Wilson answered before about "train babies" - she was born of it from the person who helped design and create the system, but within that system, so as a conjunction of father-creator and a person born in the train, she was the key.
An angle for understanding is to compare the father, Namgoong, to the Keymaker from the Matrix trilogy.